# catching the login event of ZfcUser with Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

i am using **zfcUser** with **Zend Framework 2**.

i want to capture the login event so that i can do something with it and also redirect the user to a different page.

i know how to catch the register event. ie i place a onBootstrap in my module.php file and then do the following

```
$em->attach('ZfcUser\Form\RegisterFilter','init',function($e)
```

the entire function is like this;

```
public function onBootstrap(MVCEvent $e)
{
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $em           = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        $em->attach(
                'ZfcUser\Form\RegisterFilter',
                'init',
                function($e)
                { }
}
```

However, when i tried to catch the login event i did not have any results. i.e

```
$zfcServiceEvents->attach('login.post', function($e) {
                echo "loggedn"; die();
            });
```

would really appreciate some help.

thank you.

edit:

this is how i called the registered event ( i know how to called the event for a user who has just registered. but i want to call the event when a user has just succesfully logged in

public function onBootstrap(MVCEvent $e)
    {

```
$zfcServiceEvents = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('zfcuser_user_service')->getEventManager();

$zfcServiceEvents->attach('register', function($e) {
$form = $e->getParam('form');
$user = $e->getParam('user');
```

**RESPONSE TO cptnk CODE**

in response to the answer given by cptnk i tried the following code but it did not work;

```
public function onBootstrap(MVCEvent $e)
{
$sharedManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

            $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

                $loginFunction = function ($e) use ($serviceManager) { 
                    echo "eventCaptured" ; die();
                };

            $sharedManager->attach('ZfcUser\Service\User', 'login.post', $loginFunction);

}
```

i am still not able to capture the login event.Any ideas?

cptnik had a good suggestion; he asked whether i had overridden the ZFcUser-service. in responce i clarfiy that i had overridden the zfcuser. below is the code i used;

```
'zfcuser' => array(
        // telling ZfcUser to use our own class
        'user_entity_class'       => 'BaseModel\Entity\User',
        // telling ZfcUserDoctrineORM to skip the entities it defines
        'enable_default_entities' => false,
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 /**
 * Listen to the bootstrap event
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
   $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()

   $loginFunction = function ($e) use ($serviceManager) { 
        // do something
   };

   $sharedManager->attach('ZfcUser\Service\User', 'login.post', $loginFunction);
}
```

Your code does not show what `$zfcServiceEvents` is or where it came from I assume it is a event manager referencing the zfcuser events. My approach is a little different since I attach a event to the zf2 shared manager. Maybe you have problems regarding that piece of code?

You can grab the `sharedEventManager` like so:

```
$sharedManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
```

**EDIT:** I was a little unclear on how to get the $serviceManager and the application within the Module.php `onBootstrap` function.

Comment: Hello cptnk. thank you for asnswering. i am not sure how to use the code you provided. where did you get the $serviceManager from? also. where did you get $this->app from ?

Comment: hi cptnk. i tried the above but i am still not able to capture the event. i have enclosed my revised code above

Comment: Your code looks alright to me. Did you by chance override the ZfcUser\Service\User in your module.config.php?

Comment: Hey cptnk. i did overridge the zfcuser_entity. i have enclosed above my config for overriding of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    // Handle login
    $events->attach('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain', 'authenticate.success', function($e) {
        $userId = $e->getIdentity();
        // do some stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Module.php add this:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $UserListener = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('UserListener');
    $em->attachAggregate($UserListener);
   }
```

and create src/User/Listener/UserListener.php with below code:

```
    namespace LcUser\Listener;

    use Zend\EventManager\AbstractListenerAggregate;
    use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface; 
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
    use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

 class LcUserListener extends AbstractListenerAggregate implements    ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

/**
 * @var ServiceLocatorInterface
 */
protected $serviceManager;

/**
 * 
 * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
 */
public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
    $this->serviceManager = $serviceLocator;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface
 */
public function getServiceLocator() {
    return $this->serviceManager;
}

public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events) {
    $sharedManager = $events->getSharedManager();
    $this->listeners[] = $sharedManager->attach('ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterChain', 'authenticate.success', array($this, 'userLog'));
}

public function userLog(Event $e) {

    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

    $userlog = new UserLogin(); // User Login is my User Log table to record login details as below
    $user = $em->getRepository('MyUser\Entity\User')
            ->findOneBy(array('id' => $e->getIdentity()));
    $userlog->setGroupId($user->getId());
    $userlog->setUserId($e->getIdentity());
    $userlog->setEmail($_POST['identity']);
    $userlog->setIpAddresses($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
    $em->persist($userlog);
    $em->flush();
}
}
```